# Displaying data from data reader c# in html web form

Tags: c#, html, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am using c# and i don't know how to write the data from c# in the HTML (to be available on the browser) 
Here is my code :

```
public void searchbutton_Click(object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAX-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=newSchool;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("search_name", conn);
        cmd.CommandText = "exec search_name @name";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", search.Text);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        conn.Close();

    }
```

I want to know what to write in the HTML file to take the data from the reader
Thanks

Comment: You need to add more detail to this question. What HTML file?

Comment: a HTML file of a website where there is a search textbox and i want when i perform the search the SELECTED values of the query be displayed in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

After the execute reader command do the following lines code for binding the data to the grid.
Also add a gridcontrol to the HTML to which the data has to be rendered.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table1");
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Load(read, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, ds.Tables[0]);
gridControl1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my point, I am working on a website project, and want the SELECTED values from the query to be visible on the browser. You can say that i don't know what to write in the HTML file to preview thos data

Comment: Your question is very poorly worded and lacking a lot of detail. If you add more details people can provide a better answer.

Comment: ok i will try to explain again :D
I have a database for a social network
i want to make a website for it using asp.net by visual studio
in order to get data from the database i write the c# code
so i want to display the data selected in the sql query that i called in the c# code to be displayed in the website,is that clear enough? :D

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a GridView control to display the data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx